# How to call Obervable lambda from angular template

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In component I have something like this:

```
public hasFoo$: Observable<(name: string) => boolean> = ...
```

Now i want to have several usages of this in my template with a stepper:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
  <mat-step *ngIf="hasFoo$('1st step')">
    I'm displayed when the 1st name is valid.
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step *ngIf="hasFoo$('2nd step')">
    I'm displayed when the 2nd name is valid.
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

How can I make that async? I couldnt get it to run. I tried `(hasFoo$ | async)?.call(this, '1st step')` which worked from the component, but not for my template. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have an Observable that results in a function? If so, you can write it like that:

```
<mat-vertical-stepper *ngIf="hasFoo$ | async as func>
  <mat-step *ngIf="func('1st step')">
    I'm displayed when the 1st name is valid.
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step *ngIf="func('2nd step')">
    I'm displayed when the 2nd name is valid.
  </mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

This way once your Observable return a value it would be declared as a local context variable `func` and you can call it in underlying part of the template. You would also only have one subscription.